# Regex pattern for Alpha Numeric values

Tags: regex

How can I write a regex to check that a string is alpha-numeric and has a maximum of 11 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/^\w{1,11}$/
```

`\w` means any alphanumeric character or underscore in a perl regex. If you don't want underscores:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,11}$/
```

Comment: @ithcy: POSIX character classes are rather passé in that they  tend to work only with the nasty, old-style 8-bit locales.  They don’t make much sense in a Unicode world, at least not without extensions.  It depends on whether they’re compliant with [UTS#18](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties).

Comment: Actually, `\w` in a Perl regex does not mean an alphanumunder, contrary to popular misunderstanding.  Rather, it means exactly `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Mark}\p{Connector_Punctuation}]`.  Close, but not equivalent.

Comment: @tchrist: Which characters except for alphanumeric and underscore match `\w`?

Comment: @Tim: I just told you: Marks, Connector Punctuation.  Also, Alphabetic includes Other_Alphabetic; it is certainly not just Letters.  Also, `\w` is only Decimal Numbers and Letter Numbers; there are other numeric types it does not match. You should get [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) to play around with this. You’ll likely also want [uniprops](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops) and perhaps [uninames](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames), too.

Comment: @tchrist: You are right. Looks like perlre made the same mistake: "A '\w' matches a single alphanumeric character (an alphabetic character, or a decimal digit) or '_'"

Comment: @Tim: Perl uses the UTS#18 definition of `\w` given above.  Because *Alphabetic* in Unicode comprises *Letters*, *Letter_Numbers* like Roman numerals like ⅷ and ↀ or Runic numbers like ᛯ and ᛮ, plus assorted *Diacritics* some of which are of which are *Marks* but some *Symbols* or *Punctuation*, it covers a lot more than people think. There **are** *Numbers* that are not *Decimal_Numbers*, such as the subscripted₈ and superscripted³ numbers or the fractions like ¼ or ⅗, but those are those not included in `\w`.

Comment: @tcrhist: Sure. OP did ask for alphanumerics. I was referring to the `\p{Connector_Punctuation}`, which contains eight characters except underscores.

Comment: @Tim: Strictly speaking, an “alphanumeric” would be `[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Number}]`, which is both more and less than `\w`. The only other *Connector_Punctuation* of note besides `_` U+5F LOW LINE are probably `‿` U+203F UNDERTIE, `⁀` U+2040 CHARACTER TIE, and `⁔` U+2054 INVERTED UNDERTIE. There are only 10 total *Connector_Punctuation* code points in all of Unicode (as of 6.0.0).

Answer (score 1):

Um, no.

```
 /\A[\p{Alphabetic}\pN]{1,11}\z/
```

is the right answer to the question asked.